# Getting an array's index from custom valued indexed array

Tags: c#

```
SortedList<string, int> list = new SortedList<string, int>;
list.Add("abc", 2);
list.Add("def", 3);

string index = list.GetIndex(2) ???????
Console.WriteLine(index);
```

I'm really confused. How can I get an array's index by using the index's value??

Output should be

> abc

Solutions:

Use the IndexOfValue method that SortedList exposed, with combination of the Linq extension method ElementAt(int index), so:

```
string index = list.ElementAt(list.IndexOfValue(value)).Key;//output will be abc
```

---o---

This also works

```
string index = list.Keys.ElementAt<string>(list.IndexOfValue(2));
```

Comment: I'm just as confused as you are. What array? I don't see any array.

Comment: If the 2 and 3 are just index references, why not just use a list of strings, or a dictionary of int, string?

Comment: Actually I've got an SortedList with ToolStripMenuItem as index and Form as value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `IndexOfValue` method that `SortedList` exposed, with combination of the Linq extension method `ElementAt(int index)`, so:

```
string index = list.ElementAt(list.IndexOfValue(value)).Key;//output will be abc
```

Comment: Thank you ! This also works (I've just found it)
string index = list.Keys.ElementAt<string>(list.IndexOfValue(2));

Answer (score 1):

Based on your statement that the output should be `abc`, I think you really want the `text`, not the `index`. To get the text of an item based on its `value`, simply do the following:

```
SortedList<string, int> list = new SortedList<string, int>();
list.Add("abc", 2);
list.Add("def", 3);
string text = list.ElementAt(listz.IndexOfValue(2)).Key
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Comment: There's no Property like Item in SortedList -_-

Comment: invalid arguments. list is based on string not integer.

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely right. It's correct now! I tested it and it returns `abc`.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN Documentation about SortedList.GetByIndex method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
public class SamplesSortedList  {

   public static void Main()  {

      // Creates and initializes a new SortedList.
      SortedList mySL = new SortedList();
      mySL.Add( 1.3, "fox" );
      mySL.Add( 1.4, "jumped" );
      mySL.Add( 1.5, "over" );
      mySL.Add( 1.2, "brown" );
      mySL.Add( 1.1, "quick" );
      mySL.Add( 1.0, "The" );
      mySL.Add( 1.6, "the" );
      mySL.Add( 1.8, "dog" );
      mySL.Add( 1.7, "lazy" );

      // Gets the key and the value based on the index.
      int myIndex=3;
      Console.WriteLine( "The key   at index {0} is {1}.", myIndex, mySL.GetKey( myIndex ) );
      Console.WriteLine( "The value at index {0} is {1}.", myIndex, mySL.GetByIndex( myIndex ) );

      // Gets the list of keys and the list of values.
      IList myKeyList = mySL.GetKeyList();
      IList myValueList = mySL.GetValueList();

      // Prints the keys in the first column and the values in the second column.
      Console.WriteLine( "\t-KEY-\t-VALUE-" );
      for ( int i = 0; i < mySL.Count; i++ )
         Console.WriteLine( "\t{0}\t{1}", myKeyList[i], myValueList[i] );
   }
}
/* 
This code produces the following output.

The key   at index 3 is 1.3.
The value at index 3 is fox.
    -KEY-    -VALUE-
    1    The
    1.1    quick
    1.2    brown
    1.3    fox
    1.4    jumped
    1.5    over
    1.6    the
    1.7    lazy
    1.8    dog
*/
```

Comment: I think this is not supported in NET 4.0

Comment: Refer this link. It clearly states that it is supported in all versions of .Net.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.getbyindex.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the SortedList.Values property to get an ICollection object containing the values in the SortedList object.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
SortedList<string, int> list = new SortedList<string, object>();
list.Add("One", 1);
list.Add("Two", 2);                               

int value = (int)list.ElementAt(1).Value;
```

Or...

```
int value = list.IndexOfKey("One");
```